# Vue.js Fullcalendar on date click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fullcalendar

I am trying to return a date value from the onDateClick function of fullCalendar using vue.js and pass the data to a prop I can then store in my back end via laravel. Every way I can think of just comes back with various undefined errors. I can get the modal to popup insert it just doesn't ever return a value I can see. Not sure how to get the onclick to a prop have tried dozens of combinations nothing is working here is some code.

````
import { Table, TableColumn, Select, Option } from 'element-ui';
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/vue';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import Modal from '@/components/Modal'
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid'
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction'
import BaseInput from '@/components/Inputs/BaseInput'
import flatPicker from 'vue-flatpickr-component';
import 'flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.css';
import DropzoneFileUpload from '@/components/Inputs/DropzoneFileUpload';

const today = new Date();
const y = today.getFullYear();
const m = today.getMonth();
const d = today.getDate();
export default {
  name: 'CalendarForm',
  components: {
    FullCalendar,
    Modal,
    BaseInput,
    flatPicker,
    DropzoneFileUpload,
    [TableColumn.name]: TableColumn,
    [Table.name]: Table,
  },
  data(){
    let yearAndMonth = `${y}-${m + 1}`
    return {
      calendarPlugins: [dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin],
      formData: new FormData(),
      tableData: [],
      deleteNotice: false,
      deleteId: false,
      canAdd: false,
      canDelete: false,
      events: {
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'calendar/show',
        failure: function(response) {
          console.log(response);
        },
      },
      header: {
        left: 'title',
        center: false,
        right: 'prev, next today',
      },
      showAddModal: false,
      showEditModal: false,
        model: {
          name: null,
          className: 'bg-default',
          description: null,
          start: '',
          end: '',
          files: [],
        },
        eventColors: ['bg-info', 'bg-orange', 'bg-red', 'bg-green', 'bg-default', 'bg-blue', 'bg-purple', 'bg-yellow']
    };
  },
  methods: {
      created() {
         this.init();
      },
      init() {
        window.axios.post('calendar/show')
        .then((response) => {
          this.tableData = response.data.events.data;
          this.canAdd = response.data.can_add;
          this.canDelete = response.data.can_delete;
        });
      },
      calendarApi() {
        return this.$refs.fullCalendar.getApi()
      },
      changeView(viewType) {
        this.defaultView = viewType
        this.calendarApi().changeView(viewType)
      },
      next() {
        this.calendarApi().next()
      },
      prev() {
        this.calendarApi().prev()
      },
      onDateClick({ date }) {
        this.showAddModal = true
        this.model.start = date
        this.model.end = date
      },
      save() {
      this.formData.append('name', this.model.name);
      this.formData.append('date', this.onDateClick(date));
      this.formData.append('description', this.model.description);
      for (var i = 0; i < this.model.files.length; i++) {
        const file = this.model.files[i];
        this.formData.append('files[' + i + ']', file);
      }

      window.axios.post(window.location.origin + '/calendar/store',
        this.formData,
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          },
        })
        .then((response) => {
          this.init();
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    },
    previewFiles(val) {
      this.model.files.push(val);
    },
    confirmDelete(id) {
      this.deleteNotice = true;
      this.deleteId = id;
    },
    handleDelete() {
      window.axios.post('calendar/destroy', { id: this.deleteId })
        .then((response) => {
          this.deleteNotice = false;
          this.deleteId = false;
          this.init();
        });
    },
    },
};
</script>```
````

Comment: Did you put this onDateClick inside @dateClick event?

<FullCalendar @dateClick="onDateClick" />

It should look like that one so that you will get the date.

Comment: I did in fact I have been messing around with this all afternoon and I finally have it passing a date but in an unusable format of Fri Oct 25 2019 00:00:00 GM and I need to find a way to get it into 2019-10-25 format any help would be appreciated here's a link to another question I just posted for clarification [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58551809/trouble-reformat-date-value-from-fri-oct-25-2019-000000-gm-to-2019-10-25-in-vu]

Comment: You haven't added the `<template>` part of the component in the provided code. Can you add that?

Comment: @user2345037

Use moment.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
moment("your date").format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

This one if you want to format the return date.

use moment.js

https://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 1):

Your onDateClick function is ok, and saving the date returned by Full Calendar into this.model should work (you should add a console.log at this point to verify the date is ok).
You should receive a javascript plain Date. Which is not formatted.

In your `save()` method, you need to convert this date to a format that your Laravel backend expects. Probably 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'.
For that you can use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) as suggested by @renato, or do the formatting yourself.

---

> On another note, and since I am the author **it is worth having a look at [Vue Cal](https://github.com/antoniandre/vue-cal) a Vue.js full calendar with no dependency.**

You might find this more suited to a Vue project, and easier to use. That's not a Vue wrapper that's a full Vue.js lib.

Comment: Thank you I do need to reformat the output but am having difficulty importing moment.js. I have installed it via npm install moment and can see it in my node_modules directory but when I try `window.moment = require('moment');` OR `import moment from 'moment'` I still get _ReferenceError: moment is not defined_