# trouble reformat date value from Fri Oct 25 2019 00:00:00 GM to 2019-10-25 in vue.js from method

Tags: vue.js

I have a problem getting the correctly formated date in vue.js here is the method that defines the prop

```
onDateClick({ date }) {
        this.showAddModal = true
        this.model.start = date
        this.model.end = date
      },
```

and here is the method that I get the incorrectly returned format

```
save() {
      this.formData.append('name', this.model.name);
      this.formData.append('date', this.model.start);
      this.formData.append('description', this.model.description);
      for (var i = 0; i < this.model.files.length; i++) {
        const file = this.model.files[i];
        this.formData.append('files[' + i + ']', file);
      }

      window.axios.post(window.location.origin + '/calendar/store',
        this.formData,
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          },
        })
        .then((response) => {
         location.reload();
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
```

I'm lost as to where to do the reformatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use moment.js https://momentjs.com/

```
onDateClick({ date }) {
        let formattedDate = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
        this.showAddModal = true
        this.model.start = formattedDate
        this.model.end = formattedDate
      },
```

Comment: Im getting a _reference error moment not defined_ and I have installed moment.js via npm install moment and see it in my node modules. I imported it into my vue via `import moment from 'moment'`

Comment: window.moment = require('moment');

Comment: please upvote if the answers are correct. I keep on answering your inquiries.

Comment: I have tried to use `window.moment = require('moment');` inside the method and in the import and neither works I still get reference error moment undefined

Comment: what do you mean? theat?

Comment: edited my comment above for clarity thank you for your many quick replies.

Comment: You should add it inside app.js / main.js